# Redmine plugin don't work in hudson

Tags: hudson, hyperlink, redmine, hudson-plugins

I'm having redmine 1.4.1 and hudson 2.2 installed.
after  migration the redmine 1.1 to 1.4.1, the [plugin of redmine](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Redmine+Plugin)0.9 stop working in the hudson.

When commit messages contain redmine keywords like "refs" or "closes", the redmine plugin
detects the keywords correctly, but the links contain the /show - prepending the issue number (#41), therefore getting a 404 error in redmine.

A regular link to a redmine issue:
http://myRedmineProject/issues/100

The link generated by the redmine plugin:
http://myRedmineProject/issues/show/100 
    Changes

```
 #34 (26/04/2012 10:15:29)        

    Web Service #41 e #42 — Alexandre Schossler / detalhe
    UC - TC 11 - associar produtos ao cliente #40 — Alexandre Schossler / detalhe
    cadastro de produto, configuracao do bootstrap - ref #44 #38 — carlos / detalhe
```

does anyone know how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem :D

I did check out of the [plugin](https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/trunk/hudson/plugins/redmine), i removed `show/` from code of the class `RedmineLinkAnnotator`

then i compiled using `mvn install`, copy the **redmine.hpi** to the plugins folder of the hudson

Comment: You should accept your own answer if it resolved your issue. Just make sure you leave enough detail about what you did to resolve your issue for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the source code of the plugin... But: If you have apache in front of redmine, you could - as a workaround, until the hudson plugin gets fixed - simply redirect all the `/issues/show/xxx` links.

Answer (score 1):

generate invalid issue link fix for redmine 1.4

https://github.com/ncrash/jenkins-redmine-plugin/commit/2fd1072daae4a97f85786c72d8143e6b4340b07b